# React conditionally render based on viewport size

Tags: reactjs

This should be an easy one for you React monsters. :) I have the condition written but I can't figure out how to handle the viewport size in my constructor for the condition to work. Plain and simple, I want to show one element when the viewport size is 1451px or wider and another when 1450px or smaller.

This is my code (simplified)

```
class My Class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isDesktop: "1450px" //This is where I am having problems
        };
    }

    render() {
        const isDesktop = this.state.isDesktop;

        return (
            <div>
                {isDesktop ? (
                    <div>I show on 1451px or higher</div>
                ) : (
                    <div>I show on 1450px or lower</div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Perhaps I am suppposed to work it with ComponentWillMount or ComponentDidMount. Honestly, not sure. I'm new with React.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Do you want to update `isDesktop` on page resize?

Comment: ummm, good question. I would say yes. As the user resizes, when the width falls under 1450px wide, it should render the correct component. I'm trying to workout responsiveness without CSS

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> Perhaps I am suppposed to work it with ComponentWillMount or ComponentDidMount

Yes, you need to listen for `resize` event and update internal state on change. You can do it by adding event handler when component mounts. Try full example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpwz13ykx4).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDesktop: false //This is where I am having problems
    };

    this.updatePredicate = this.updatePredicate.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updatePredicate();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updatePredicate);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updatePredicate);
  }

  updatePredicate() {
    this.setState({ isDesktop: window.innerWidth > 1450 });
  }

  render() {
    const isDesktop = this.state.isDesktop;

    return (
      <div>
        {isDesktop ? (
          <div>I show on 1451px or higher</div>
        ) : (
          <div>I show on 1450px or lower</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That was Gold! I understand the concept now. I should be able to use this concept in other conditions I have to work out. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, thoroughly shows the architecture of a conditional state change.

Answer (score 38):

Just to post a recent update here after I had the same issue, but set it up using a functional component and the `useEffect` / `useState` React Hooks:

```
const MyFunction = () => {
  const [isDesktop, setDesktop] = useState(window.innerWidth > 1450);

  const updateMedia = () => {
    setDesktop(window.innerWidth > 1450);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateMedia);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateMedia);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {isDesktop ? (
        <div>I show on 1451px or higher</div>
      ) : (
        <div>I show on 1450px or lower</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

if you use **NextJS** ... you will have an error like : **window is not defined**.
Here is the code with no error, enjoy.

First i check if the size of the window if more or less 1450px( because if the user never resize the window all the code will be useless )

But i also need to check if the user resize the window ... see by yourself

```
    export default function MyFunction() {
        const [isDesktop, setDesktop] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1450) {
      setDesktop(true);
    } else {
      setDesktop(false);
    }

    const updateMedia = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth > 1450) {
        setDesktop(true);
      } else {
        setDesktop(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateMedia);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateMedia);
  }, []);
    
      return (
          <div>
              {isDesktop ? (
                  <div>I show on 1451px or higher</div>
              ) : (
                  <div>I show on 1450px or lower</div>
              )}
          </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Awesome solution!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But instead of repating "window size comparision code" you can just call updateMedia() (after the function is defined in side the useEffect) You already have this code inside the updateMedia function.

Answer (score 4):

the issue with your code is that it only works if the resizing happens, here I have the `handleWindowResiz` function will set the width to the `window.innerWidth` and compares it to the `breakPoint` to conditionally render your UI, if the user resizes the screen the event listener will be triggered and the `handleWindowResiz` will be called and it will reset the `width` to the new `window.innerWidth` and you get your desired UI. So the UI is always rendered correctly when the component is first rendered and when the user resizes the screen width.

```js
const MyFunction = () => {

  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
  const breakPoint = 1450;

 

  useEffect(() => {
   const handleWindowResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
   window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);

    
   return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
      {width > breakPoint? (
        <div>I show on 1451px or higher</div>
      ) : (
        <div>I show on 1450px or lower</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explain what are you doing with your code.

Comment: when the component is rendered in the first time the handleWindowResize function will set the initial width and then we compare the width with the breakPoint to chose what should be rendered <div>I show on 1451px or higher</div> or  <div>I show on 1450px or lower</div> , and when the window is resized the event listener will be triggered and the width will be reset to the new window width. so what is different here is even when the component is first rendered we can get the window width and do our conditional rendering. I hope I was able to explain myself well :)

Comment: Please put the explanation in the *answer*, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
class My Class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          isDesktop: window.innerHeight > 1450,
      };
  }

  render() {
      const isDesktop = this.state.isDesktop;

      return (
          <div>
              {isDesktop ? (
                  <div>I show on 1451px or higher</div>
              ) : (
                  <div>I show on 1450px or lower</div>
              )}
          </div>
      );
  }}
```

Here more info [Get viewport/window height in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs)

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, also the innerHeight caught my attention. Aren't you handling the Height instead of the width? I mean to handle the width of the viewport. I tried innerWidth and it didn't work either. I haven't checked the link you provided though

Comment: You can create resize listener, with callback function where you can change state of isDesktop, currentlly this implementation work only on refreshing page