# next.js styles doesn't update on first render

Tags: next.js, styles, antd, styled-components, server-side-rendering

Using next.js with SSR I'm having a strange problem.

My website renders as expected server-side and is served to the client with styles. There are no surprises here when I'm visiting the website on a laptop everything looks as expected.

However, when I visit the website on a mobile device (or simulated smaller window), the first render is rendered with the same styles as my desktop styles, even though my mobile media query returns `true`

I'm using https://github.com/wintercounter/use-breakpoint for most of my media queries.

Which looks like this:

`const { 'isMobile-': isMobileMinus } = useBreakpoint()`

and my layouts etc. should change based on whether `isMobileMinus` is true or false.

For example, this antD component is supposed to switch from horizontal to vertical if it's a mobile device.

`<Space size="middle" direction={isMobileMinus ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal'}>`

What is really interesting is that when I render the webpage in a small window the size of a mobile device I can console log `isMobileMinus` to be `true`, but my components do not update until I either resize the window (and it's true again) or I navigate to another page and back.

It acts as if `isMobileMinus` was false, but only for that specific component.

I can even render the value of `isMobileMinus` in the component and it will render `true` on first render, but the components I have acts as if it was false until I make another update.

I find this very strange as the component is clearly re-rendering with the correct value, but it does not update the styles of the components that were styled via SSR?

This problem is not just limited to the above hook based media queries but also other things.

For example I have 2 buttons that are rendered on SSR called "login" and "Signup" which are supposed to be white and green respectively.

However when the webpage renders if the user is already logged in. It should render 2 new buttons called "Log out" and "Dashboard" which are red and blue respectively.

But somehow on first render. The text of these buttons will update to logout and dashboard, but the styles of the buttons will be white and green (incorrect).

These are completely different components, but next.js still keeps the old styles?

```
  if (loggedIn) {
    return (
      <Space>
        <LogoutButton onClick={handleLogout} />
        <DashboardButton onClick={handleDashboardClick} />
      </Space>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Space>
      <LoginButton />
      <SignupButton onClick={showSignup} />
    </Space>
  )
```

There seems to be some really strange thing with next.js where it will update the content of the HTML, but refuses to update the CSS when a component is re-rendered on the client-side.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

I tried making a copy like suggested here: [How to immediately re-render client-side using React + NextJS after initial server-side render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715846/how-to-immediately-re-render-client-side-using-react-nextjs-after-initial-serv) which seems to be a similar issue.

```
  const breakpoints = useBreakpoint()
  const copy = lodash.cloneDeep(breakpoints)
  const { 'isMobile-': isMobileMinus } = copy
  console.log(' ~ isMobileMinus', isMobileMinus)
```

But that did not work for me either.

I'm on `"next": "11.0.1",`

---

I found 1 solution but it feels more like a hack than a solution.

If I wrap my components in `process.browser && (<Component />)` then the component will not render during SSR, and only render client-side.

This causes the component to render correctly when the webpage is loaded.

But of course I would ideally like to take advantage of SSR, and just update the styles client side :(

Note that this hack also causes console errors, so it is definitely not recommended. It seems like the use-breakpoint library is incompatible with SSR frameworks.

Comment: how did you solve this problem

Comment: @j10 I never found a solution. I'm still using the hacky workaround. Hoping some one will eventually post a solution to this. If you solved it, please let me know!

Comment: I had similar problem which was caused by custom `_document.tsx` and [layout system](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts). I work with `renderPage()` function which is available inside the `getInitialProps()`. I just needed to make sure the returned value from this function is the same as the one returned in `_app.tsx`. So in context of [layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts) I needed to wrap the component to layout associated with a page. That fixed my issue. Hope it helps.