# React track height of div in state?

Tags: reactjs

I found the code snippet from [this answer for tracking page size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42141641/773263) to be useful. I want to switch `window.innerHeight` with `$("#list_container").height`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { width: 0, height: 0 };
  this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateWindowDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
}

updateWindowDimensions() {
  // !!! This works:
  this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
  // !!! This doesn't work:
  this.setState({ width: $("#list_container").width(), height: $("#list_container").height() });
}
```

*Edit: Updated to `.width()` and `.height()`, had tried both but neither is working for me.*

List container is defined in the same module as the outer div:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div id="list_container">
      <ListGroup>
        <VirtualList
            width='100%'
            height={this.state.height}
            itemCount={this.state.networks.length}
            itemSize={50}
            renderItem={({index, style}) =>
              <ListGroupItem
                onClick={() => this.updateNetwork(this.state.networks[index].ssid, this.state.networks[index].security)}
              action>
              {this.state.networks[index].ssid}
            </ListGroupItem>
          }
        />
      </ListGroup>
      <Modal/>
      // ...
```

Note:

If I do:

```
<p>{this.state.height}</p>
```

It isn't `0` just empty, with the example that doesn't work.

Comment: Does $("#list_container") return the correct element?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda sorry, I'm not sure how to check. I added a snippet that shows where I defined it. How can I check?

Comment: Inside of your `updateWindowDimensions` method, you can do a `console.log($("#list_container"))`.

Comment: Or just open up your dev tools and paste $("#list_container") in the console. It should return the element you are trying to measure.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda it finds the object but it has no property for `.height()` or `.height`

Answer (score 1):

If it's jQuery you're using, `width()` and `height()` are functions, not properties. Try:

```
this.setState({ width: $("#list_container").width(), height: $("#list_container").height() });
```

Comment: thanks, tried also not working, going to update my question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use refs since the js might be running before the component renders to the dom.

[React documentation on refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
render() {
  return (
    <div id="list_container" ref={ el => this.componentName = el }>
      // ...
```

to reference this dom node in this component you just have to call this.componentName

```
updateWindowDimensions = () => {
  $(this.componentName).height()  // returns height
}
```

Comment: Inside `componentDidMount`, all of the DOM nodes should be mounted on the screen already ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)).

I do agree with you that `refs` are the recommended way to break out of the React abstraction.

Comment: Thanks but it returns 0 for me

Comment: true, it was not the best example... it would be necessary for `updateWindowDimensions`

Comment: wait let me try something else I didn't have it in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: does your list container have height? it may show 0 if its children are absolutely positioned, in which case you would have to look into a clearfix solution to get the proper height

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Erics answer using refs, to pull it off without jQuery, you can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```
const listRect = document.getElementById('list_container').getBoundingClientRect();
```

or if using the ref from Erics answer:

```
const listRect = this.componentName.getBoundingClientRect();
```

followed by

```
this.setState({ 
  width: listRect.width, 
  height: listRect.height
});
```

I would suggest [this page](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) for some good examples of life without jQuery.

Also, I would strongly suggest debouncing the resize handler.

Comment: sorry, not sure where to put it. Trying in `componentDidMount()` but it seems to stay 0.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, hard to say without seeing your full code, but that would seem to indicate that the list container contents haven't rendered yet. Is that a separate component or coming in a callback?

Comment: I added a bit to the question. I think I need to use this but run after rendering like you say.