# React, client mobile or desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Building server side rendered application with React and NextJS. I want to know the  width of the viewport and distribute it through the whole application via props. Getting the width of the viewport is the easy part:

```
window.innerWidth;
```

My problem is the following:

- Only in the `render` and `componentDidMount` methods is the window object available.
- We can't set props in the `render()` method because this would make the function impure
- Checking to see if the viewport width in `componentDidMount` could work, but now we have already rendered the component.

Is there any way to get `window.innerWidth` before the render method is triggered?

P.S. the solution doesn't have to be passing it via props per se. It could be another solution which helps tackling this issue.

Comment: Maybe this is a case for context?  https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html  Why does your JS need to know about the viewport width?

Comment: So I can conditionally render components

Comment: Based on the viewport

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get viewport/window height in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs)

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen did you found a solution to this? Or is there any good solution you are using currently and would share with others having the same issue.