# preventing rerenders on change in windows height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs), i can get the height and width of the window

but on change of height or width of the window, it causes rerenders, losing all data that has been previously entered

```
function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}

 function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}



const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
```

this causes text input to lose focus and lose any data that may have been entered there

here is a video to see the effect on android
https://photos.app.goo.gl/cadqLsnsmW46ZGDy6

Comment: Maybe you could debounce the event somehow? the resize event happens relatively often. If that's the issue.

Also what data loss are you talking about? Could you show this in code?

Comment: data loss from inputs

Comment: Could you please create a minimal example showing this?

Comment: in code or  how?

Comment: ok, when i click on the text input field,and the keyboard comes up on android, surely the height of the window is affected, thereby causing the page to reload

Comment: Yes, in code if you could

Comment: i'll make a screen record and post the link here

Comment: i have added a video link