# React: CSS Grid number of rows relative to screen size & store what data is displayed on each page

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, css-grid, display

I'm making an app with React, similar to Spotify and SoundCloud in functionality. Please look at the below image of my design...[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm using `display: grid` to display the Record components. Is there a way using display grid I can remove the components that don't fit on the screen and then display those components on the next screen? I have done some research on this and found `Virtual Scrolling`. I don't think this is the tool I'm looking for though because from what I understand that applies to only scrolling, and serves a function similar to Google search.

What I'd like to do is have a way to declare
what Record components belong on what page, relative to how many are displayed on each page.

My code looks like this for displaying the Records...

```
  <DisplayRecords theme={theme}>
    {albumData.map((album) => (
      <Record
        name={album.album_name}
        shadowColour={album.album_shadow}
        photo={album.album_photo}
        theme={theme}
      />
    ))}
  </DisplayRecords>

const DisplayRecords = styled.div`
  height: calc(100% - 4.7rem);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0rem 4rem;

  // grid things
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 8rem;
  grid-row-gap: 8rem;
`;
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should do this through CSS as your pagination content is probably handled by your javascript code.

You can check the value of `window.innerWidth` in your React code ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs)), and according to that, divide the elements of `albumData` into chunks ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)). Then you can display each chunk as being the content of a "page", and display the next chunk of records when clicking on the "Next page" button.