# How to remove outline from Material UI button using by breakpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui, conditional-statements

I want to remove the `outlined` variant at the small medium and down breakpoint. To do this, I have tried to do the following:

```js
const variantType = theme.breakpoints.down('md') ? '' : 'outlined';

<Button name="buyFood" variant={variantType} onClick={this.openFoodModal}>
  Buy
</Button>;
```

This does not do the job. I have tried researching and no one seemed to ask this question before. So here is the first of its kind. lol

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using the [`useTheme`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#usetheme-theme) and the [`useMediaQuery`](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/) hooks from Material UI.

```js
import { Button, useTheme, useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core'

export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const mediumDown = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button name="buyFood" variant={mediumDown? 'text' : 'outlined' } onClick={this.openFoodModal}>
        Smart Suggest
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Button variant controlled by media query]

Comment: By far the more elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can access your theme settings with the [`useTheme`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#usetheme-theme) hook if you have custom theme.

After that you only have to compare the current window `width` with your breakpoint.

To do this you can simply write a hook that gives you the current window `width`.

[Here is an elegant solution from @QoP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs)

This could then look like this:

`./App.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import useWindowWidth from "./useWindowWidth";

export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const width = useWindowWidth();

  const variantType = width < theme.breakpoints.values.md ? "text" : "outlined";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button name="buyFood" variant={variantType} onClick={this.openFoodModal}>
        Smart Suggest
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`./useWindowWidth.js`

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const getWindowWidth = () => window.innerWidth;

export default function useWindowWidth() {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(getWindowWidth());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowWidth(getWindowWidth());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowWidth;
}
```

### Live demo:

[image: Edit heuristic-dirac-otz93]