# What happens to default server-side values in Remix?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, remix.run

I'm using the following hook (taken from [Get viewport/window height in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs)). I've adapted the hook so it can be rendered on the server (by gating access to `window` inside a conditional).

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function getWindowDimensions() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
    return {
      width,
      height
    };
  }
  return { width: -1, height: -1 }
}

export default function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```

I've noticed something interesting / confusing:

1. The hook does return the default values of `{width: -1, height: -1}` when it is rendered on the server
2. These values are seemingly observed by parent component. Example:

```js
export default function FooComponent() {
    const { width, height} = useWindowDimensions();
    // this invariant fails
    invariant(width > -1 && height > -1);

}
```

However, if I insert a `console.log(width, height)`, below the `invariant(...)` line, I never see `-1, -1` in the browser console.

So it looks like the `invariant` is only triggered on the server and `console.log` is only run on the client. Can someone explain what's going on here? I.e, why does the component not observe default server side values?

Answer (score 1):

Is it invariant from https://github.com/zertosh/invariant ?

A note on the readme says that if `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not `production` it'll throw even if condition is true.

And for component that should only render client side, there is a cool package by SergioDXA (a top remix contributor) : https://github.com/sergiodxa/remix-utils#clientonly