# Check for Windowsize React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

What I am basically trying to create is a navbar that has two completely different html hierarchy based on the window size. I want it to be different for mobile than for a desktop version. eg a nav bar that is on the right on desktop and one that is on the top for mobile.

A simply state of what was doing. I created a `const` that would use a state of the screen size. I had used the `useState()` to get a default for now but I know that if I was first loading on desktop and it it was defaulted to mobile. I would have to resize first to get the desktop version instead.

```
const [sizeState, setSizeState] = useState("mobile");
const changeNavbar = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 900) {
        setSizeState("mobile"); 
    } else {
        setSizeState("desktop"); 
    }
};

window.addEventListener('resize', changeNavbar);
```

the `sizeState` would then call an if function determines what state it currently is set to.

```
if (sizeState === "mobile") {
    return ( //some code for mobile) }
else {
// return some code for desktop
 }
```

for now it always returns the mobile version even if loading upon a innerwidth that is above 900 abd only on resize it would do something.

I have been trying to use a onload stuff and an eventlistener that would listen to load. but i cant manage to call the `changeNavbar` function on the first load of the page.

I saw people recommending to use `useMediaQuery` but I don't know how to get it to work based on my `if (mediaquery is set to md) { return( mobile navbar) }`

If someone could help me use the `useMediaQuery` in this instead of my previous attempt, so that I can have two separated returns I would also be soooooo thankful for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get viewport/window height in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 4):

1. You can simply implement it using [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) and [styled-breakpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-breakpoints) packages and its hooks API.

   Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-breakpoints-n8csvf

```js
import { down } from "styled-breakpoints";
import { useBreakpoint } from "styled-breakpoints/react-styled";

export default function App() {
  const isMobile = useBreakpoint(down("sm"));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isMobile ? "Mobile View" : "Desktop View"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Or you can create custom hooks like this: https://github.com/jasonjin220/use-window-size-v2

```js
import useWindowSize from "use-window-size-v2";

export default function App() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowSize();

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h1>useWindowSize Hook</h1>
      <p>
        height: {height}
        <br />
        width: {width}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use a simple hook like that:

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';

export const useAddEventListener = () => {
  const addEventListener = useCallback((
        target: HTMLElement | Window,
        eventKey: string,
        event: (e: Event) => void
    ) => {
        target.addEventListener(eventKey, event);
        return () => target.removeEventListener(eventKey, event);
    }, []);
  return { addEventListener };
};
```

And then call it:

```
const { addEventListener } = useAddEventListener();
addEventListener(window, 'resize', (e) { 
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
})
```