# How to listen to width of page - React

Tags: reactjs, header, width

I have 2 headers. I want to render the first one when width > 768px, and second one when < 768.

I tried this :

```
const [isMobileResponsive, setIsMobileResponsive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMobileResponsive(window.innerWidth < 768);
  } , [window.innerWidth]);

return (
    !isMobileResponsive ?
       <p>header1</p>
         :
       <p>header2</p>
)
```

**The problem with this :** when I go to chrome responsive feature, and resize the size of the screen, React does not re-render and don't change the header.
I have to reload the page to get the new Header.

How can I do this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track the window's width in react you can make a custom hook to handle window resizing such as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862334/get-viewport-window-height-in-reactjs).
But in this concrete case I think you would be better off using CSS media queries with a mobile first approach.

```css
.navbar-desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .navbar-desktop {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The code above hides the `.navbar-desktop` by default only showing it if the width of the viewport is greater than 768. Doing the exact opposite for the `.navbar-mobile`.

Comment: I don't know why I wanted to set a state. CSS is perfect. Thank you very much and sorry for the dumb question !

Answer (score 0):

Simply add resize `Event Listener`

```
const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  const handleResize = (e) => {}
  
  return <div>Test</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

##### You can do it by creating a class somewhere and writing `display: none;` inside of it. After doing so you can get the screen width with `screen.width`.

```css
    const viewerFunc = (yourContainerId) => {
        const overview = document.getElementById(yourContainerId);
        overview.classList.toggle('d-none');
    }
```

```html
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
"Screen width is " + screen.width;
```

or you can do it as *@David Machado* suggested with CSS.

```html
display-desktop{
  // your codes
  display: none;
}

display-mobile{
  // your codes
  display: flex;
}


  // Mobile version of your app
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  
  display-desktop{
    display: flex;  
  }
  display-mobile{
    display: none;
  }
  
  }
```